# Can you please help me translate this title and signature?

Tags: translation, characters, meaning-in-context, character-identification

[image: I]

I am trying to translate this signature from a watercolor painting I bought many years ago at a thrift store.  I've tried google translate along with searching Asian artist seals, but no luck.

Comment: 水鄉䥫堃(author)寫(painted)。The seal: 金＋夷 or 銕。(This Q will be closed soon.)

Comment: I re-opened this question because @Dalice705 has shown that prior research and effort was made; as per our requirements: **unless prior research effort is clearly indicated**.

Answer (score 1):

The translation of 水鄉 is "water town". In China, "水鄉" usually refers to "江南水鄉", which are the villages/ town in the Yangtze River Delta (e.g. Suzhou Zhouzhuang Water Town). "鐵" is iron. 
According to Kangxi Dictionary, "堃" means compliance, obedience, female and is the variant of "坤". "坤" is one of the Bagua("八卦" or the eight trigrams) and it represents "地" (earth/ground/floor).  "寫" is writing or painting.